# Cairo with tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, cairo

Is it possible to draw on a Cairo Surface and then display that as a tkinter.PhotoImage? Could somebody provide an example or at least a description of how one would do this?

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a few ways to achieve what you want and tkinter.PhotoImage is definitely not the best one, unless you really have to use it. The simplest one is to use [ImageTK module from Pillow library](https://pillow.readthedocs.org/reference/ImageTk.html?highlight=tkinter):

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from cairo import ImageSurface, Context, FORMAT_ARGB32


class ExampleGui(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        w, h = 800, 600

        self.geometry("{}x{}".format(w, h))

        self.surface = ImageSurface(FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
        self.context = Context(self.surface)

        # Draw something
        self.context.scale(w, h)
        self.context.rectangle(0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.context.set_source_rgba(1, 0, 0, 0.8)
        self.context.fill()

        self._image_ref = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (w, h), self.surface.get_data(), "raw", "BGRA", 0, 1))

        self.label = Label(self, image=self._image_ref)
        self.label.pack(expand=True, fill="both")

        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleGui()
```

Otherwise you can do it by converting cairo's surface to base64-encoded GIF image(either with the help of Pillow or manually, which is going to be a little bit time consuming) and passing the result as "data" arg to tkinter.PhotoImage constructor(**untested!**):

```
    from io import BytesIO 
    from PIL import Image
    from cairo import ImageSurface, Context, FORMAT_ARGB32


    w, h = 800, 600

    surface = ImageSurface(FORMAT_ARGB32, w, h)
    context = Context(surface)

    output = io.BytesIO()
    image = Image.frombuffer("RGBA", (w, h), self.surface.get_data(), "raw", "BGRA", 0, 1)
    image.save(output, format="gif")
    b64 = base64.b64encode(output.read())
```

**Note:** On big-endian machines "ARGB" mode should be used for the source data AFAIK.